# How to pass request object through promise chain

Tags: node.js, sql-server, scope, es6-promise

I am trying to get the request object as part of the `then` statement using the Node.js `mssql` package.

However, when I try to log it out, it is undefined.

```
exports.someFunction = (proc, req, res) => {
  sql.connect(config.properties).then((pool, req) => {
    return pool.request()
      .execute(proc)
      .then((response, req) => {
        console.log(req) // undefined
    })
  }
```

How can I pass the request object to the `then` statement for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined three separate function arguments as `req` so they all hide each other and you've tried to declare a 2nd parameter for a `.then()` handler which doesn't exist so of course it will be `undefined`.

You can direct access variables in the parent scope so that's all you need to do here:

```
exports.someFunction = (proc, req, res) => {
  return sql.connect(config.properties).then((pool) => {
    return pool.request()
      .execute(proc)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(req) // can directly access the req in the parent scope
        // do something with `req` here
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep scope, perhaps a better way would be to write this as async/await:

```
exports.someFunction = async (proc, req, res) => {
  const pool = await sql.connect(config.properties)
  const result = await pool.request().execute(proc)
  console.log(result, req) // both retain scope
})
```

}

But I think the reason why req is undefined in your console.log is because in:

```
sql.connect(config.properties).then((pool, req) => {
```

You are expecting req to be passed to you as a result of the `.then()` (which is a shadowed variable). If you remove it from here and the other `.then()` then it should also work